# The post request works in Postman and in cURL but not in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, express

I have a remote server and a local client which sends a simple post request with one header `Content-Type: application/json` and with the body  `'{"text": "hello"}'`.

The server code is here. It prints the request body and the header.

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/home")
    .all(bodyParser.json())
    .all(function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body, req.headers['content-type']); // !!! print to console body and header
        next(); 
    })
    .post( (req, res, next) => {
        res.status(200).json({
                    message: req.body,
                })
            }
    );

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PATCH, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});
app.use('/api/v1', router);

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

The post request works fine from Postman and from curl.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://vm-gudiea.sio.lab.emc.com:3000/api/v1/home' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{\"text\": \"hello\"}'
```

For both requests the server prints the following body and `content-type` header.

```
{ text: 'hello' } 'application/json'
```

But I need to send the request from my Angular app. I have the following method in a service there

```
sendInitialRequest(): void {
    const myHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post(this.remoteUrl, JSON.stringify({text: 'hello'}), {headers: myHeaders})
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

But if I call the method remote server will print the output

```
{} undefined
```

So it didn't get a `Content-Type` header and body for some reason. Where is the bug here? How can I send a post request with body and header from an Angular app ?

Comment: Can you check please if you are not getting CORS policy problem in your browser console ?

Comment: @GuilhermeAlencar yes, I get this problem in Chrome but not in FireFox

Comment: Then maybe you should consider using some proxy to workarround this. This article explains a bit about it (it's not especifically toward angular) https://medium.com/@theflyingmantis/cors-csrf-91ba8487c5fd

Comment: Do you see an OPTIONS request going out first? If yes, does it respond with a 200 AND has the correct cors headers in the response headers?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you meant. The fact is, your server requested has different triplet (scheme/host/port) than your front-end's triplet. Most of browsers block it (including firefox)

Comment: @GuilhermeAlencar The solution below solves it for any of browser. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is related to cors, install this package in you API
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

then use it as following

```js
import * as cors from 'cors';

...

app.options('*', cors());
app.use(cors());
```

**other tipps:**

do not stringify your JSON in the angular request.
also there is not need to explicitly set the json header, angular will take care of that for you.

```js
this.http.post(this.remoteUrl, {text: 'hello'})
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. I get the error in both cases with `stringify` and without it.

Comment: can you also try removing the headers? since im pretty sure angular will set the correct headers for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have cross-origin error. Try this:

```sh
npm install --save cors
```

```js
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

cosnt app = express();

app.use(cors());
/* your regular routes go here */
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the issue. Thanks a lot!